# Maven build fails. While it can find all dependencies, it cannot find the classes defined in the project

Tags: java, maven

When I build my maven project (I always use clean) it fails and gives me cannot find symbol error.
This is my pom.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rabbit-producer</groupId>
    <artifactId>customer-user</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1-cp1</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20140107</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- The client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hotspot JVM metrics-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_hotspot</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Exposition HTTPServer-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_httpserver</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Pushgateway exposition-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_pushgateway</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
            <artifactId>sentry</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.29</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.company.UserMain</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

When I run it with -X it shows the following exception:

```
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
```

Maven can recognize and resolve all the dependecies and classes. It only has problem with resolving the classes I have defined myself in project.
It sounds irrelevant to me but just to have mentioned it here I had added it as a module to a project in intellij, though I'd be surprised if it has any effect on the project itself.

Comment: `Compilation failure`....not resolving is a problem there is a compiling problem with your code...

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes naturally when it cannot recognize my classes it cannot compile it. mvn compile gives the same error. While I am 100% sure my class is there.

Comment: Can you create that project on Github ...?

Comment: I don't have the right to put the code on github. But I see no reason it fails here and succeeds there.

Comment: Are your source files correctly located in `src/main/java` plus package name and your tests in `src/test/java` plus package name? Can you post the code part which is shown with the compile errors otherwise it's impossible to help...